# Glass with no borders

Tags: ps4, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft on PS4. I tried to get the glass to have no borders but I have no clue how to. I have tried OptiFine but it can't download because it isn't supported on the PS4, so I want to know another way. I mean mixed textures something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by no borders? You mean you want the glass to be completely clear?

Comment: @Robbie They want smooth textures, e.g putting lots of glass blocks together does [this](https://prnt.sc/qog2tq) rather than [this](https://prnt.sc/qog315).

Comment: This feature is commonly known as connected textures, maybe this helps with your research

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is an OptiFine feature, and mods aren't supported on the PS4. There may be texture packs which remove the borders from glass, but they won't have borders around the outside.